# export MATLAB cell array into a csv file

Tags: arrays, matlab, export-to-csv, cell-array

I wish to write a some information in form of a csv file from a MATLAB code.

In the MATLAB code I have stored the header as a cell array:

```
ToCSV={'Location' 'Weight_factor' 'Average' 'Maximum' 'Minimum'};
```

I append rows to this cell array *by looping*. A sample statement is:

```
ToCSV={ToCSV; {'EastLocation' 0.5 1e+3 1e+4 1e+2} };
```

I wish to print this as a csv file. I used following routine which sort of giving errors:

```
fid = fopen('outfile.csv','w');
fprintf(fid,'%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n',ToCSV{1,:});
fprintf(fid,'%s, %f, %10.2e, %10.2e, %f\n',ToCSV{2:end,:});
fclose(fid);

>>Error using fprintf
>>Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

Can some of you please provide pointers to achieve this?
I also tried `csvwrite`, but apparently it doesn't go well with cell arrays.

Comment: what version are you running on?

Comment: @XiaoleiZhu, my MATLAB version is R2012a

Comment: I was gonna suggest using tables and `writetable` function, but I guess that might not be available in your version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the following statement

```
ToCSV={ToCSV; {'EastLocation' 0.5 1e+3 1e+4 1e+2} };
```

This makes a cell array inside a cell array so that when you index `ToCSV` you get a cell array.  I think you want to concatenate a row like this:

```
ToCSV=[ToCSV; {'EastLocation', 0.5, 1e+3, 1e+4, 1e+2} ];
```

or

```
ToCSV(end+1,:) = {'EastLocation', 0.5, 1e+3, 1e+4, 1e+2};
```

The commas just make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
aa=ToCSV{1,:};
bb=ToCSV{2,:};
fid = fopen('outfile.csv','w');
fprintf(fid,'%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n',aa{:});
fprintf(fid,'%s, %f, %10.2e, %10.2e, %f\n',bb{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: He's looping.  When the concatenation runs a second time, this breaks.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for pointing out. I +1 to your answer, that works.